# How do I install libqwt-qt4-dev on ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: compiling, qt

I'm trying to compile [gplates](https://gplates.org) from source, since there isn't currently a .deb file for 20.04 fossa yet, but it requires using qt4 and subsequently qwt for qt4. Is there any way I can install the required libraries to compile the program within 20.04, or am I stuck? The dependencies file calls for `sudo apt install libqwt-dev`, but this doesn't seem to exist any more.

Comment: You can install QT4 libraries from PPA: https://launchpad.net/~rock-core/+archive/ubuntu/qt4/?field.series_filter=focal . About `libqwt-dev`, you can try to download the package for eoan version, but I don't know if it will fit all dependencies: https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/libqwt-dev (check the links in the table at the end of the page)

Comment: Qt4 is EOL and was removed from Ubuntu in 2019 (2015 upstream was announced EOL though Debian & Ubuntu supported it until 15-Mar-2019) ; (for more details refer https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/removing-qt-4-from-ubuntu-before-the-20-04-release/12295). The package if maintained should have been ported to Qt5 (introduced 19-Dec-2012) before now

Comment: Thanks @LorenzKeel for the response, unfortunately libqwt-headers is installed at a later update than the one required by libqwt-dev in the eoan package, so I don't think this is possible for me to do at this point in time unless I can have 2 versions of libqwt-headers installed simultaneously. Looks like this program is a no-go until the next update!

Answer (score 0):

I just managed to do it (for `tartini`) as follows:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rock-core/qt4
sudo apt -y install libqt4-opengl libqt4-svg
sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/libqwt5-qt4_5.2.3-1_amd64.deb
# after downloading it from the bionic repository
```

I wish someone would pick up [Tartini](https://www.cs.otago.ac.nz/graphics/Geoff/tartini/) ...